# how can I select this text in XPATH?

Tags: xpath

I have this div, I want to select the postal code with the city. All the selecter I used were getting the whole div, or without the right data.

```
<div class="merchantContact">
    <h2 class="subHeadline firefinder-match">L' Autre Pied</h2>
    5-7&nbsp;Blandford Street<br>
    London&nbsp;W1U 3DB                <-------------------I want this line
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.lautrepied.co.uk" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;"><font color="#0891be">Company Website</font></a><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
html/body/div/text()[3]
```

A test with [`firePath`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firepath/) `firefox` addon :

[image: desc img]

---

Maybe you need to be more specific in your [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression, so try this :

```
//div[@class="merchantContact"]/text()[3]
```

Comment: whaH!, work in your firefox.............Im trying too......but nothing. Awesome....

Comment: nono, I dont know, but I see in your firefox work, thanks a lot, its only that in my case doesnt work. But thanks

Comment: finally I tried another checker, and your solution worked. THe weird thing is that in my firebug XPATH didn't work. THanks.